# How can I manage a new NSMenuItem?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

I'm adding menuItems by code.

I'm using the "selector" but my problem is because I have a "mutable" menu where I dont know how many rows it will have, so I need to manage each one but not knowing how many are.

Perhaps with the code I can explain better the problem.

I have a loop as follow (more or less)

```
for (punterolineas=punterolineas; punterolineas <= intNumlineas; punterolineas++)

{
    NSDictionary *dic = [lineas objectAtIndex:punterolineas];
    NSMenuItem *item = [[NSMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:[dic objectForKey:@"txtMostrado"]action:@selector(menuitem:) keyEquivalent:@""];//Where menuitem is  to manage the item, but I need to identify which one it is.
    [item setTarget:self];
    [statusMenu addItem:item];
}
```

I think that the answer could be the "sender" of the "menuitem" IBaction, but how can I manage it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "manage the IBaction"? You can set the `action` property of the menu item using the `-setAction:` method.

Comment: Yes, sorry, It needs more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several approaches:

- Set the `tag` of each menu item. In the action method (`-menuitem:`), check `sender`'s tag and decide what to do. In your case, you might use `punterolineas`, assuming the `lineas` array will remain the same for the lifetime of the menu items.
- Set the `representedObject` of each menu item. In the action method, obtain the `representedObject` of the `sender` and use it to control what you do. In your case, you might use the `dic` as the `representedObject` if it has the information to control what the menu ought to do.
- Use a proper model object — an instance of a custom class — instead of an `NSDictionary` to represent the lines. Have the menu item target the model object instead of `self`. Use a method of that model class rather than a method of the class containing the above code as the action method. Again, this requires that the line objects live at least as long as the menu items.

Comment: Thanks!
Finally I'm using the [sender title], it is not the best for my objective, but it could be work.
Thanks a lot dor your tips!

Comment: You're welcome. Using the title is almost never the right approach.